# Bash Mapfile Var Adds Space

Tags: bash, echo, whitespace, global, var

I'm stumped as to why this happens.

I would like to paste a multiline var from an interactive prompt into a mapfile and then work with said mapfile as if a file object.

I can live with the echo breaking for some reason and using printf but why the added leading space upon assigning the mapfile var to another (global) var?

```
#!/bin/bash

global_privkey=""

myfunc(){
  local input_pattern

  # Paste SSH privkey.
  builtin echo "paste your privkey:"
  builtin mapfile input_pattern

  # Adds leading space!
  builtin echo "echo (adds space):"
  builtin echo "${input_pattern[@]}"

  # Works.
  builtin echo "printf (good):"
  builtin printf "%s" "${input_pattern[@]}"
  builtin echo

  # Adds leading space!
  global_privkey="${input_pattern[@]}"
}

myfunc

# Leading space!
builtin echo "global printf (adds space from var assignment):"
builtin printf "%s" "$global_privkey"
builtin echo

exit 0
```

Output:

```
arch :: ~/scripts % ./input_privkey_minimal.sh
paste your privkey:
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW
QyNTUxOQAAACCzzWDcxsfWJ0NI15wBtPLqQPfryYDSZz8jN+eSk7+pdAAAALD7CKEF+wih
BQAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUxOQAAACCzzWDcxsfWJ0NI15wBtPLqQPfryYDSZz8jN+eSk7+pdA
AAAED6QmKlvu9ASHyHHBm7oLq7l2AMglXKq+uJ9IlbZBDbc7PNYNzGx9YnQ0jXnAG08upA
9+vJgNJnPyM355KTv6l0AAAAKHJvYmVydEAxMDItMTgyLTE1NS0zNS5pcC5hZnJpaG9zdC
5qb2J1cmcBAgMEBQ==
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
echo (adds space):
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
 b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW
 QyNTUxOQAAACCzzWDcxsfWJ0NI15wBtPLqQPfryYDSZz8jN+eSk7+pdAAAALD7CKEF+wih
 BQAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUxOQAAACCzzWDcxsfWJ0NI15wBtPLqQPfryYDSZz8jN+eSk7+pdA
 AAAED6QmKlvu9ASHyHHBm7oLq7l2AMglXKq+uJ9IlbZBDbc7PNYNzGx9YnQ0jXnAG08upA
 9+vJgNJnPyM355KTv6l0AAAAKHJvYmVydEAxMDItMTgyLTE1NS0zNS5pcC5hZnJpaG9zdC
 5qb2J1cmcBAgMEBQ==
 -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

printf (good):
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW
QyNTUxOQAAACCzzWDcxsfWJ0NI15wBtPLqQPfryYDSZz8jN+eSk7+pdAAAALD7CKEF+wih
BQAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUxOQAAACCzzWDcxsfWJ0NI15wBtPLqQPfryYDSZz8jN+eSk7+pdA
AAAED6QmKlvu9ASHyHHBm7oLq7l2AMglXKq+uJ9IlbZBDbc7PNYNzGx9YnQ0jXnAG08upA
9+vJgNJnPyM355KTv6l0AAAAKHJvYmVydEAxMDItMTgyLTE1NS0zNS5pcC5hZnJpaG9zdC
5qb2J1cmcBAgMEBQ==
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

global printf (adds space from var assignment):
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
 b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW
 QyNTUxOQAAACCzzWDcxsfWJ0NI15wBtPLqQPfryYDSZz8jN+eSk7+pdAAAALD7CKEF+wih
 BQAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUxOQAAACCzzWDcxsfWJ0NI15wBtPLqQPfryYDSZz8jN+eSk7+pdA
 AAAED6QmKlvu9ASHyHHBm7oLq7l2AMglXKq+uJ9IlbZBDbc7PNYNzGx9YnQ0jXnAG08upA
 9+vJgNJnPyM355KTv6l0AAAAKHJvYmVydEAxMDItMTgyLTE1NS0zNS5pcC5hZnJpaG9zdC
 5qb2J1cmcBAgMEBQ==
 -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: See `mapfile -t`

Comment: **DELETE REVOKE YOUR PRIVATE KEY** because you have just published it here

Comment: Replace `[@]` by `[*]` if you want a single string.

Comment: Wow! All the great help and answers. Amazing people! Thank you.

Comment: @LéaGris: the SSH key was disposable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some fixes to your script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

global_privkey=""

myfunc(){
  local input_pattern

  # Paste SSH privkey.
  echo "paste your privkey:"
  mapfile -t input_pattern

  # Adds leading space!
  echo "echo (adds space):"
  echo "${input_pattern[@]}"

  # Works.
  echo "printf (good):"
  printf %s\\n "${input_pattern[@]}"
  echo

  # Delete BEGIN END entries
  unset 'input_pattern[0]' 'input_pattern[-1]'

  # Join lines into a single string
  printf -v global_privkey %s "${input_pattern[@]}"

}

myfunc

# Leading space!
echo "global printf (adds space from var assignment):"
printf %s\\n "$global_privkey"
```

Answer (score 2):

> why this happens.
>
> Adds leading space!

Sure it does - `echo` delimits arguments by spaces.

```
$ echo '1'       "2"           3
1 2 3             # wow single spaces
```

```
$ a=(1     2    '3     var     with  spaces')
$ echo "${a[@]}"
1 2 3     var     with  spaces       # arguments contents are preserved
```

When you pass multiple arguments to echo, these are delimitered by spaces.

`mapfile` doesn't remove the trailing delimiter from array elements. So each array element ends with a newline. Additionally `echo` outputs a second newline, so two newlines are printed out, resulting in an empty line.

```
$ a=(1$'\n' 2$'\n' 3$'\n')    # mapfile leaves newline in variables
$ set -x
$ echo "${a[@]}"
+ echo '1
' '2
' '3
'      # executes echo with 3 arguments, each with a newline
1
 2     # echo outputs values separated by spaces
 3
       # echo outputs extra newline
```

```
# the echo "${a[@]}" is equal to:
$ echo 1$'\n' 2$'\n' 3$'\n'
1
 2
 3

$
```

And when array is expanded with `${array[@]}` in assignment the array elements are concatenated using the first character in IFS, space by default. It's equal to `${array[*]}` in that context (because "words" are concatenated together on assignment).

```
$ set -x
$ a=(1 2 3)
+ a=(1 2 3)
$ echo "${a[@]}"
+ echo 1 2 3  # passes 3 arguments
1 2 3
$ echo "${a[*]}"
+ echo '1 2 3'  # passes 1 argument separated by first character in IFS
1 2 3
$ ( IFS='|'; printf "%s\n" "${a[*]}"; ) # well known method for printing arrays
+ IFS='|'
+ printf '%s\n' '1|2|3'
1|2|3
$ b="${a[@]}"
+ b='1 2 3'   # wow, spaces
$ b="${a[*]}"
+ b='1 2 3'   # * will be equal to @ in assignment
```

Arrays expansions with `[*]` and `[@]`  are handled similar to `$*` and `$@` are handling with positional arguments. For more extensive examples I recommend [Posix Rationale for Shell and Utilities C.2.5 Parameters and Variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_05), it's with `$*` `$@` but it's the same with arrays.